# Japanese Kana Keyboard on iOS doesn't work properly with capital English letters on input react js

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, cjk, ime

Faced with a really weird problem with the Japanese keyboard on iOS.
I'm doing the application localization+customization for the Japenese locale and we also support mobiles.

If you add `Japanese - Kana` keyboard on iOS and then while inputting press `ABC` it will allow you to switch to English letters within the same keyboard, presenting in the look like the keyboard on old cell phones.

The problem that if I want the user to input only capital letters I do really simple `onChange` event handling on React, but in case I use specifically this keyboard at the input of the second letter it's going to duplicate the previous ones.

React code (app generated using create-react-app):

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const TextInput = ({handleChange, value}) => {
  return (
    <input onChange={handleChange} value={value}/>
  )
};

const TextField = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState();

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    
    const value = event.target.value;
    const upperCaseString = value.toUpperCase();
    debugger;
    setValue(upperCaseString);
  }

  return (<TextInput handleChange={handleChange} value={value}/>)
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

1st input:

[image: It's correct and works as expected]

event.target.value === 'a'

2nd input:

[image: It's incorrect since some of the letters are duplicated (a)]

event.target.value === 'Aad';

Here is the error! I only pressed `d` it should be `Ad` instead.

I think it's the keyboard specific behavior that it's ignores the capital letters that are already present and if I debug it I'll that on each `onChange` there still will be the regular small letters.

I want eventually to have the regular string without duplicates all letters uppercase.

Guys do you have any ideas about what the hell is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why you're wrapping what is just an `<input>` element by an entire functional component. Why does `TextField` not return `<input onChange={handleChange} value={value}/>`? Keeping it simple makes debugging much easier.

Comment: Also please make those screenshots a **lot** smaller. Cut out that massive amount of whitespace (that contributes nothing to folks understanding what you're showing them) and scale them down to a normal size.